# Strongly connected components of a graph just a disjoint union of cycles

Tags: algorithms, graphs

While reading corman book, i just came across examples to find strongly connected components in a directed graph. But it turns out be disjoint union of cycles. Is this true for all directed graphs?

What about biconnected components? are they also disjoint union of cycles? please correct me if am thinking wrongly

Comment: Try writing a few examples and see if you can find a counterexample...

Comment: Sir from examples only I saw this observation. Can u please point to some links at least?